# How does this bash function work?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, dash

I'm looking at [this short example](http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/20255), and I don't see how this function works:

```
function EXT_COLOR () { echo -ne "\[\033[38;5;$1m\]"; }
```

AFAIK `-ne` stands for not equal. What are we comparing here? I only see one variable (string): `"\[\033[38;5;$1m\]"`. It looks like it echoes the result of comparison, but there is no variable it compares to.

Comment: Nope, nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-ne` only means "not equal" when it's in an `if [ … ]` statement. In this case `-ne` is an option to `echo`. You could just as easily use `-en`.

From `bash(1)`:

> If  `-n`  is  specified,  the trailing newline is suppressed.  If the `-e` option is given, interpretation of the following  backslash-escaped  characters  is enabled.

In this example there is no comparison. Just `echo`.

Comment: Possibly more clearly, you could also just as easily use "-n -e" -- it's two options, echo just supports merging them together under a single dash because it's unambiguous